# Difficulties with or reprimands for passing COVID hotspot?

Tags: germany, covid-19

Tomorrow I will drive from the Cologne area to Mecklenburg-Vorpommern.
The shortest route would be via A2 and pass right through Kreis Gütersloh, currently infamous for being a COVID hotspot.
Should I prefer to take another route even if it is an hour longer?
Do I have to expect any checks on the Autobahn there?
Do I have to expect trouble entering Meck-Pom after passing there? I know that Meck-Pom is very restrictive with visitors *from* the Gütersloh area without a very recent negative test

Comment: Since the likelihood of getting infected while driving at a speed of around 100 km without stopping through an infected area where the infected persons have been isolated is 0.0000000%, you should have no problems.

Comment: Are there travel restrictions within Germany ?

Comment: @Max There are restrictions for persons who **reside** inside lockdown areas to stay in other states. This effects persons registering in a hotel and giving an address from that area. The term being used is **Beherbergungsverbot**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The likelihood of getting infected while *not* working in that slaughterhouse is also quite low. My concern was not for getting infected

Comment: *The likelihood of getting infected while* not *working in that slaughterhouse is also quite low.* – Well, but when living in that area there is a considerably increased likelihood that you encountered somebody during your daily activites who worked there, are contracted the virus that way. That’s quite a different thing.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen have you reached Mecklenburg, eventually?

Answer (score 3):

The Gütersloh and Rheda-Wiedenbrück areas of Germany has certainly seen a sharp rise in cases which appears to have originated in the Tönnies meat processing factory and spread into the community.

Restrictions are however limited to those who reside in the area, until at least the end of June 2020 (lets see if these will be extended or not).

They include such things as:

- Closing of schools and Kindergartens
- Restrictions on contact between households
- Further restrictions on restaurants (some have chosen to close completely)
- Bars, Cinemas, fitness studios, etc must close
- Other businesses must implement strict hygiene protocols
- etc.

There are also restrictions on where people from the area can travel to, even within Germany with people having to prove to be virus free.  But these only apply to residents of the area.

But there are no restrictions on driving through the area.  All Autobahns and major Bundesstrassen roads remain open as normal.  And there are no restrictions on people who have driven through the area who have not spent time there.  There are no additional controls or checks on the borders between states within Germany.

Even if you did stop in the area, e.g. to refuel, so long as you follow the general guidelines of wearing a mask, washing your hands etc. then there should be no need to worry.
You would need to spend some time with an infected person to catch the virus (how long exactly has not been determined by scientists, but figures of 10-15 mins have been mentioned).

You will almost certainly not catch it by just driving through the area in your car.  And hence the restrictions in place reflect this, and apply only for residents.

Comment: *There are also restrictions on where people from the area can travel to, even within Germany with people having to prove to be virus free. But these only apply to residents of the area.* How are those restrictions enforced? Self-declaration?

Comment: @Relaxed There is no single rule, and each state is determining individually what should apply. 
This can include a 14 day quarantine period or a recent negative test (normally within 48 hours).

Comment: @Relaxed This is enforced when peaple register in hotels, pensions, camping places. Based on their ID, person from (at present) 2 counties can only stay if the have a medical certificate issued in the last 48 hours. Most states have passed laws to this effect that came into force on the 27th of June.

Comment: OK, what about Mecklenburg-Vorpommern then? What's their rule and *how do they enforce it*? Do they go by your officially registered address? Call on people from Gütersloh to report themselves to the authorities to get a test? Can there be spot checks by the police (as there were in France or Italy)? This seems to be the gist of the question to me.

Comment: @MarkJohnson What I hear from Jason and yourself is that there is no enforcement outside of commercial accommodation and they only check the address written on German citizen's ID. No chercks along transportation networks, no other criteria like recent travel, etc. I think this could be made clearer in the answer. The rest isn't terribly relevant.

Comment: @Relaxed The problem is, that it is rather confusing. The regulations for berlin are also different than the other states - Berlin regulations (english) : Part 3 - Quarantine Measures
§ 8, 9 [SARS-CoV-2 Infection Protection Ordinance - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/corona/en/measures/directive/)

Comment: It is also a dynamic situation which has developed quickly.  The restrictions in the affected Landkreise in NRW were only put in place until the end of June, and it is still (as of the time of writing) still not clear what will happen after that.  And the states putting in place travel restrictions are adapting quickly themselves.  In many cases they are not applying it only to the impacted regions, but to any region where the number of cases exceeds 50 in 100k, so one also needs to monitor which regions have exceeded this value to get a full picture.  Which changes daily.

Comment: @Relaxed These measures require peaple to inform the authorities if they have been insided an infected area within the last 14 day (whether inside or outside of Germany). Since in general, no travel records are kept an amount of voluntary cooperation is being assumed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't know about Gütersloh, but in some house complexes that were put under quarantine recently in Göttingen, they erected a mobile fence (like for construction work) when there were suspicions that some of the inhabitants would not comply with the quarantine. So the checkpoints are directly in the quarantined area (also not all of the Gütersloh county is under quarantine, only some houses and areas) rather than all over the county. Similar routines were also used some month ago with a local outbreak in Thuringia where they put one village under quarantine.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX That is a different situation (enforcement of a quarantine). The situation here is based on the enforcement of the **Beherbergungsverbot** (Prohibition of accommodation) defined in the Mecklenburg-Vorpommern Ordinance (Corona-LVO MV)
of 8. Mai 2020: [§4(2), which references §5 (8)(1,2)](http://www.landesrecht-mv.de/jportal/portal/page/bsmvprod.psml?showdoccase=1&st=lr&doc.id=jlr-CoronaVSchVMV2rahmen&doc.part=X&doc.origin=bs).

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX §5(1) defines a general entry ban into the state of Mecklenburg-Vorpommern (MP). §5(2-9) defines exceptions to (1), but also conditions where the exception do not apply. §5(8) applies to persons booking at least for 1 night. §5(8)(1) to persons with a residence in abother german state, but not from areas with more than 50 per 100k. §5(8)(2) to all others, but not from an area defined as a high risk area outside of Germany. **Nothing** is stated how it is to be enforced.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX §4 defines under what conditions accommodations can be offered, but excludes those who are not allowed entry into MP as defined in §5. The former Berlin Ordinance was similar in nature to the MP one, but has been cut in half and greatly simplified, because nobody could make head or tails of what it meant.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: I understand that and I should have been clearer: what I wanted to point out is that there are areas inside Kreis Gütersloh where one isn't even supposed to drive through, but this is nothing that one would do accidentally, and these are very localized areas. OTOH, looking at the MV directive, I have to say that this IMHO a bit weird. Very restrictive against tourists, e.g. pure transit not being allowed. But no whatsoever restrictions to persons that go there for professional purposes - including even those from  Gütersloh.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Yes, but these exceptions (for medical personal, transporters etc.) have existed in most countries since the beginning of the pandemic. For Gütersloh the restrictions have just been extended for another week. For the 2nd county (Warendorf) it will not be renewed.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Transit always assumes you are allowed in on the other side, where at present the same restrictions apply.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Someone from, say, Hamburg would be allowed to go to, say, Brandenburg for vacation without problems. But they'd not be allowed to enter (and transit) MV without booking at least one night's accomodation (for a distance of 100 km highway). But this is getting very much off topic.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Please remember this is an evolving situation and the Ordinance was written where only essential travel was allowed. § 5 is titled: **Travel *to* Mecklenburg-West Pomerania**, in the since of to and remaining. Even so, §5(9) may apply in this case since you are travelling through (and not staying in) to where you are allowed to enter: Persons who are in Mecklenburg-Western Pomerania and for whom no exception according to paragraphs 2 to 8 applies, must leave the state of Mecklenburg-Western Pomerania immediately, regardless of the day of their entry.